# Express making mongodb data available in route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs, embedded-javascript

This seems like a relatively simple issue, but I can't seem to find good documentation. I'd like to pass json data from mongodb into a route, so that it is available in my ejs template.

My schema is:

```
var GiveSchema   = new Schema({
    title: String,
    shortname: String,
    contents: String,
    image: String,
    category: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GiveData',  GiveSchema);

var Givedata = mongoose.model( 'GiveData' );
```

I'd like to pass make it available to my route below, as the variable list:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs',{
      list: Givedata,
      bootstrappedUser: req.user,
      page: 'home'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll still need to query the database for your items.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {       
   Givedata.find(function(err, items){
     if(err) { return next(err); }
     res.render('index.ejs',{
       list: items,
       bootstrappedUser: req.user,
       page: 'home'
     });
  });
});
```